# Characterization of adjunctions via universal elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, solution-verification, adjoint-functors

I'm trying to formulate a statement that would characterize adjoint functors in terms of "universal elements", and I'm trying to make the statement look like Theorem 2.2.5 and Theorem 2.3.6 in [Leinster's text](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375). Below is my attempt.

---

**Background/Notation**: the (dual version of the) Yoneda lemma gives a natural bijection $$[\mathscr A,\mathbf{Set}](H^A,X)\simeq X(A)$$
given from left to right by $\alpha\mapsto \hat\alpha$ where $\hat\alpha=\alpha_A(1_A)$, and from right to left by $u\mapsto \widetilde u$ where $\widetilde u_B:H^A(B)\to X(B)$ is given by $f\mapsto X(f)(u)$.

---

**Proposition.**

Let $F:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B,\ G:\mathscr B\to\mathscr A$ be functors. Let $X: \mathscr A(A,G(-)):\mathscr B\to \mathbf {Set}$.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between

(a) adjunctions between $F$ and $G$ (with $F$ on the left and $G$ on the right);

(b) elements $u\in X(F(A))$ such that for every $B\in\mathscr B$, $\widetilde u_B$ is a bijection.

---

Did I formulate the proposition correctly? (I'm only interested in the statement, not in its proof; I'll prove it myself.)

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. Could you prove it?

Comment: @Berci I think it follows more or less directly from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071066/proving-the-equivalence-of-two-definitions-of-adjoint-functors-without-using-the). Namely, assign to an adjunction with unit $\eta$ the $A$th component $\eta_A$ of its unit. Condition (b) in this question with $u=\eta_A$ is equivalent to condition (b) in the cited question, and then it follows from the cited question that the assignment I described above is a bijection.